# What are the network requirements of running a bitcoin node?

Tags: bitcoind

I have been hosting my bitcion node in a simple Kuberenetes setup (without istio). I recently learnt about istio https://istio.io/ and want to use it for hosting my bitcoin node.

However, I am not sure about the egress values that need to be configured for the bitcoin node to discover and communicate to other peers. What's the correct way of `istio` egress configuration for bitcoind?
More specifically, what are the hosts that I should allow bitcoind to communicate to?

Answer (score 1):

To operate, Bitcoin Core needs to:

1. make DNS queries to a number of public domains in order to find peers to connect to, a full list of these is in [chainparams.cpp](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/src/chainparams.cpp)
2. make arbitrary outgoing connections on TCP port 8333 on IPv4, IPv6, or both
3. optionally accept incoming connections on TCP port 8333